# How can I preserve whitespaces with python 2.7 lxml?

Tags: python, lxml

I have a huge xml file (thousands of lines) and I need to change some attribute parameters.
Xml looks like this:

```
<person id="name" name="pers_name">
    <group id="Common">
        <emotion id="smile">
            <texture texture="smile" x="-131" y="-17" />
            <effect name="name1" x="51" y="438" />
            <effect name="name2" x="61" y="419" />
            <effect name="name3" x="55" y="312" />
        </emotion>
     </group>
 </person>
```

After I did it and wrote it with `tree.write(path, encoding='utf-8', xml_declaration=True)` I lost whitespaces before closing tag.
How can I preserve it?

```
<person id="name" name="pers_name">
    <group id="Common">
        <emotion id="smile">
            <texture texture="smile" x="-131" y="-17"/>
            <effect name="name1" x="51" y="438"/>
            <effect name="name2" x="61" y="419"/>
            <effect name="name3" x="55" y="312"/>
        </emotion>
     </group>
 </person>
```

Code

```
from lxml import etree

# Offsets
x_offset = -10
y_offset = -20

tree = etree.parse(path)
XML = tree.getroot()

for effect in XML.iter('effect'):
    texture_offset_x = int(effect.get('texture_offset_x')) + x_offset
    texture_offset_y = int(effect.get('texture_offset_y')) + y_offset
    effect.set('texture_offset_x', str(texture_offset_x))
    effect.set('texture_offset_y', str(texture_offset_y))

tree.write(path, encoding='utf-8', xml_declaration=True)
```

Comment: I assume you want to preserve the whitespace because you want to run some difference tool on it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting 'xml:space' to 'preserve' Python lxml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17476749/setting-xmlspace-to-preserve-python-lxml)

Comment: Yep, my diff tool is going crazy :)

Comment: Any particular reason to use `lxml`? You can recompile it to add whitespace before the tag closure but unless you need its features it's not really worth the trouble.

Comment: No. But I think lxml easier. I used xml.Etree but it sorts attributes alphabetically

Comment: Snce whitespace (at least at that point) is irrelevant for XML, you're way better off finding a diff tool that handles XML properly (.e.g, newlines should also not make a difference), instead of fixing this on your side.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12176239/how-to-compare-xml-files

Comment: @DenisKorablev - True, but it will print the tags with your desired whitespace and its easier to monkey-patch it to use [`collections.OrderedDict()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) to preserve the attribute order than to modify `lxml` (or rather the underlying [`libxml2`](https://github.com/GNOME/libxml2), specifically [`xmlwriter.c`](https://github.com/GNOME/libxml2/blob/master/xmlwriter.c)'s [`xmlTextWriterEndElement()`](https://github.com/GNOME/libxml2/blob/master/xmlwriter.c#L1162) function) and recompile it for each platform you may use it on.